# while designing a Java EE application the package org.eclipse.swt.dnd is showing error

Tags: apache, tomcat, swt

The problem which i have faced while designing the interface
is as follows:

For incorporating the feature of drag and drop i am using SWT and all
the SWT drag and drop classes are defined in the package
`org.eclipse.swt.dnd`.Now my problem is that while developing a
standalone application i have included the external jar named
`swt-4.2.1-win32-win32-x86` and it is working fine. But while
developing a Java EE application if I include the package
`org.eclipse.swt.dnd` within a jsp page like 
`<%@page language="java" import="org.eclipse.swt.SWT"%>` it shows the following errors:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: [16] in the generated java file:
[C:\javaPrograms\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\work\Catalina\localhost\wanem\org\apache\jsp\wanem_jsp.java]
```

Only a type can be imported. org.eclipse.swt.SWT resolves to a package

```
Stacktrace:
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
Tomcat/7.0.37 logs.
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use pure desktop GUI framework in web application..?

Comment: actually i want my application to be web based,not a standalone one.so that user can browse it from there browsers easily.

Answer (score 0):

SWT is for writing desktop applications and will not work in a JSP. You may want to take a look at [Remote Application Platform](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/rt.rap).